# Using Android Purchase Status API: Not found

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've an android application and it's using the "Google Play In-app Billing" library to purchase in-app.

I've read that is better to verify purchases in a backend server using the Purchase Status API (Google Play Android Developer API v1.1).

I've found an example about how to obtain the refresh token, how to use it to obtain a access token, and how to use the API.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("10.12.54.8", 8080, "http");

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
ApacheHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new ApacheHttpTransport(client);

JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();   

TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();        
tokenResponse.setAccessToken(accessToken);
tokenResponse.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
tokenResponse.setExpiresInSeconds(3600L);
tokenResponse.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications");
tokenResponse.setTokenType("Bearer");

HttpRequestInitializer credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setClientSecrets(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET).build().setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

AndroidPublisher publisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(GOOGLE_PRODUCT_NAME).build(); 

AndroidPublisher.Inapppurchases purchases = publisher.inapppurchases();
Get get = purchases.get(GOOGLE_PACKAGE_NAME, ITEM_ID, purchaseToken);
InappPurchase purch = get.execute();
```

But I'm receiving a 404 Not Found. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did this work out for you?